# Why do we take equal dimension of layers during addition of multiple neural networks outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I was reading some project that involves dealing with both image & text-sequence input at the same time, I  was wondering why do we take same dimension in **Keras** **add()** function when we combine outputs from the different neural network in **Dense layer**

**Q1**: Is there any benefit of doing this?

**Q2**: If we take non-equal dimension in add( ) or merge( ) will it affect model performance ?

**Q3**: Also can we consider  this as a another hyper-parameter and tune it to get the best fit of model ?

this was the structure
[image]

Comment: I think here it's just a design choice rather than an architectural constraint.

Comment: Oh,so there isn't any benefit of doing this ? if we take non-equal dimension in add( ) or merge( ) will it affect model performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add()` requires tensors of the same dimensions. So you simply can't use an add() operation with different dimensions.

Addition of a matrix (N, A) with a matrix (N, B) only makes sense if A == B, for values of A and B > 1. When A or B == 1 you can apply broadcast rules.